# Implementing reload method in C++ Thrift Server

Tags: c++, multithreading, thrift

I'm using Apache Thrift framework, I'm writing an application, that has C++ server and python client. The application has a big resource object, that are used during the life. My application needs to have a reload method. It should delete all resources, and load new instances from the disk. I wrote the cleaning method, and calling it before load method. That's work, if I use TSimpleServer(one-threaded). But when I'm starting to use ThreadedServer or TNonBlocking server(multi-threaded), cleannig method doesn't work, as I can see, It's calling but it doesn't clean. Server just starting to use twice amount of memory. I tried to use a mutex during cleaning method, but that didn't help. 
For me,it's seems the matter is in multithreading, remote methods starts in the child thread, so they can't release resources that were allocated in the main thread.

```
template<typename T>
void deleteProcessors(T &processor) {
    for (typename T::iterator iter = processor.begin(); iter != processor.end(); ++iter) {
        delete iter->second;
    }
    processor.clear();
}

class taggerHandler : virtual public taggerIf {
public:
    taggerHandler() {
        this->loadResources();
    }

    void tagText(std::string& _return, const std::string& text, const std::string& language) {
        //useful function
    }

    void reload(std::string& _return, const std::string& parmeters) {
        this->clearResources();
        this->loadResources();
    }
    private:
        void loadResources() {
            //here config reading,  option declaring etc..
            //maco just object from freeling library, could allocate >100MB
            string language = "en";
            this->macoProcs[language] = shared_ptr<maco>(new maco());
        }
        void clearResources(){
            macoProcs.clear();

            //this way was before shared_ptr
            //deleteProcessors(macoProcs);
        }
        map<string, shared_ptr<maco> > macoProcs;

        //this way was before shared_ptr
        //map<string, maco*> macoProcs;
};
```

Thrift Initialization:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
shared_ptr<taggerHandler> handler(new taggerHandler());
shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new taggerProcessor(handler));
shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

shared_ptr<ThreadManager> threadManager = ThreadManager::newSimpleThreadManager(15);
shared_ptr<PosixThreadFactory> threadFactory = shared_ptr<PosixThreadFactory>(new PosixThreadFactory());
threadManager->threadFactory(threadFactory);
threadManager->start();

//TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
TNonblockingServer server(processor, protocolFactory, port, threadManager);
server.serve();
return 0;
```

}`

Comment: (1) Can you add your Thrift server protocol stack setup? (2) Have you checked the `maco` DTOR get's called and executes correctly on `macoProcs.clear()`?

Comment: Aded Thrift stack ini. As for clear method: When I were using raw ptrs  I was sure, becasuse it's easy to check `delete` operator. For now I'm sure only because it's works in one-threaded mode.

Comment: Guarding each entry point with a mutex or the like should help in your case, I agree with that. If it doesn't help, then it could be that there is something within the FreeLing source that prevents (at least) this part from being used in an MT environent. - EDIT: the page at http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/ states "FreeLing **3.1 is thread-safe**, allowing parallel processing (e.g. in webservices)."

Comment: You mean put mutex on write methods, such as reload, or put mutex on `tagText` (useful method that only reads) too? If first, I already tried this when I were using raw ptrs.

Comment: Exactly. Either you did it wrong (which I assume is not the case, but I can't tell for sure based on the code shown above) or your version of the library does not fully support this. Since I'm not a FreeLing expert, this is merely educated guesswork, but it is very likely that it is *not* a Thrift issue.